# Unable to iterate a list and compare strings python

Tags: python, list

I am new to python programming and I really need help in comparing values in a list.

I have two lists(drink,food) .I'm not doing a comparison between two lists. What i am trying to do is comparing all the values within a list by itself.

So, I have to first compare all the values in drink list first using a for loop and an if-else statement. If there's a match in drink, I will do another for loop for food list and compare the values in food list using an if-else statement.

These are my code:

```
drinks = []
food = []

drinks.append("lemontea")
drinks.append("coke")
drinks.append("sprite")
drinks.append("orangejuice")
drinks.append("fantagrape")

food.append("nugget")
food.append("pizza")
food.append("chickenwing")
food.append("fries")
food.append("pizza")

for i in drinks:
    if i == drinks:
        for j in food:
            if j == food:
                print("fail")
    else:
         print("success")
```

My issue is that I am supposed to be getting an 'failed' output as I have the same item in the food list that is pizza. Also, i'm not sure why am i getting 5 success output when im expected to get either only 1 'failed' or 'success' output.

This is my output i got:

```
success
success
success
success
success
```

I would appreciate if any help was given. Thank you.

Update:
Thanks for the reply but however, it seem that people are confused with my question, hence im providing more information.

The reason why i have to compare each item in a list is because the items are generated randomly and are of string type which are then appended to the list. For example, the first item generated is '00100ABC'and so on. So in case, there are duplicate values/item in the list, i have to give an error message.

Comment: One thing you definitely have wrong is your condition: `if i == drinks:` is not correct. You are checking a value of drinks against the list. You are ultimately comparing a string to a list for your equality and will certainly always fall in to your else case.

Comment: `if i == drinks` is like saying if each letter is the entire alphabet.

Comment: Also, I'm not making the connection in your logic of why you have to have to have a nested list like that. Also, what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your looping logic. It doesn't quite make sense to me.

Comment: @idjaw changed the values and object in the list because i am not allowed to post the actual item. But either way, i have to do a for loop and compare the drink list first and if there's a match, i will do the same thing for food list next.

Comment: @ShammelLee so i tried using if i == drinks[i], but i gotten an error saying "list indices must be integers, not str"

Comment: Could you explain exactly how you want to compare each list with itself? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: @ShammelLee not as in each list but rather each item in the list.

Comment: @DanielWinser see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44381292/3682217)

Answer (score 0):

```
#So you have
#drinks = ['lemontea', 'coke', 'sprite', 'orangejuice', 'fantagrape']
#food = ['nugget', 'pizza', 'chickenwing', 'fries', 'pizza']

for i in drinks:
    if i == drinks:
        for j in food:
            if j == food:
                print("fail")
    else:
         print("success")
```

iteration 1

```
i = 'lemontea'
if i == drinks:
```

Here you are evaluating does 'i==drinks', 
where drinks is a list object and i is a string object.
As i and drinks are not equivalent, (they are different objects with different values)
the if statement evaluates to False,and
executes the else statement, which prints success.

iteration 2

```
i = 'coke' 
if i == drinks
```

Again, you are evaluating the string object 'coke' with the list object drinks,
which is False. This same condition applies to all conditions.

What you need to do is change your code to work with indexes

```
eg. 
drinks[0] = 'lemontea'
drinks[1] = 'coke'
drinks[2] = 'sprite'
ect...
food[0] = 'nugget'
food[1] = 'pizza'
food[2] = 'chickenwing'
```

to compare identical positions for equivalency use index

```
for i in range(0, len(drinks)):
    if drinks[i] == food[i]:            #compare index for index
        print('Matching index')
    else:
        print('Index does not match')
```

Now this will not work if the item in the index's are not orderd in both list, eg so nuggets may not be in index 2 in both lists. To see if the item occurs in both lists regardless of order use 'in'

```
for item in food:    #eg item 0 = 'lemontea'
    if item in food and item in drinks:
        print(item, 'is in both lists')
    else:
        print(item, 'does not occur in both lists')
```

Hope that helps.

---

Edit

```
for x in food:
    while food.count(x) > 1:  #breaks loops when only occurrence left.
        print("There are", food.count(x), 'occurrence of', x, 'in food')
        food.pop(x)
        print("deleted one occurrence")
```

This loop tests each item in the loop for more than one occurrence and deletes all but one.

Alternative cleaner method. - use sets as it removes duplicates by definition.

```
unique_in_food = list(set(food))   #sets remove all duplicates by definition

now if you want unique items across multiples lists

unique_in_both = list( (set(food) | set(drinks) )
# set(a) | set(b)    finds the union between two sets
```

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply. However, it seemed that your explaination is to compare both food and drink list together. I'm not trying to compare drink list with the food list. What im trying to do is to the compare the drink list by itself and then the food list by itself

Comment: Why are you trying to compare the list with itself? Can you give an example of how you would use it?

Comment: im not allowed to post the actual items but i can tell you is that the item are generated randomly and appended to a list. But i have to ensure the items are not the same. Hence, i have to compare each and every item in the list and if there's a duplicate, i have to give an error message.

Comment: I still don't fully understand you, my maybe these tools will help. count(), use it to count how many occurrences of an item are in a list. Or use sets to keep track of unique items.

Comment: @DanielWinser so the actual problem is you want to check for duplicates.

Comment: @ShammelLee yes, I want to check for duplicates in a list alone.

Comment: What do you want to do with the duplicates, delete them?

Comment: @rosh i have to give an error message and remove them from the list

Comment: @DanielWinser you should include this new information in your question.

Comment: @rosh, i tried your edited answer and it work. But i have a question, is there a way to break the while loop assuming the food.pop(x) isn't in it

Comment: all the x's tested will always be in food as it check 'for x in food'. There is also an easier way to do this check using sets.

Comment: Okay check now, that last one is how I would do it in the fastest and cleanest method. If you could select my answer it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check the `pizza` value exist in food list or not, you just need do like this:

```
def insertValue2List(list, value):
    if value not in list:
        list.append(value)
    else:
        print("fail")

drinks = []
food = []

insertValue2List(food, "nugget")
insertValue2List(food, "pizza")
insertValue2List(food, "chickenwing")
insertValue2List(food, "fries")
insertValue2List(food, "pizza")
```

the output is :

```
fail
```

If you just want delete the duplicate value in list, you can used the sample code:

```
print(list(set(food)))
```

The output is :

```
['pizza', 'nugget', 'chickenwing', 'fries']
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. Does this check the other values e.g nugget. chickenwing, fries as well or just the pizza value?

Comment: The `set() `  element must uniqueness, so if the duplicate list element will be direct remove.

Answer (score 0):

This prints on success and failure and also removes duplicates…

```
drinks = []
food = []

food.append("nugget")
food.append("pizza")
food.append("chickenwing")
food.append("fries")
food.append("pizza")    

# let's add some duplicates…
drinks.append("lemontea")
drinks.append("fantagrape")
drinks.append("fantagrape")
drinks.append("coke")
drinks.append("orangejuice")
drinks.append("sprite")
drinks.append("fantagrape")
drinks.append("lemontea")
drinks.append("fantagrape")
drinks.append("sprite")
drinks.append("sprite")
drinks.append("orangejuice")
drinks.append("orangejuice")
drinks.append("coke")
drinks.append("coke")

food.append("chickenwing")
food.append("nugget")
food.append("pizza")
food.append("fries")
food.append("chickenwing")
food.append("nugget")
food.append("fries")
food.append("pizza")    

for drink in drinks:
  occurences = [index for index, value in enumerate(drinks) if value == drink]
  if len(occurences) > 1:  # if duplicates occur
    print('fail: {}'.format(drink))
    occurences.pop()  # keep one occurence
    [drinks.remove(drink) for o in occurences]  # remove the rest
  else:
    print('success: {}'.format(drink))

for meal in food:
  occurences = [index for index, value in enumerate(food) if value == meal]
  if len(occurences) > 1:  # if duplicates occur
    print('fail: {}'.format(meal))
    occurences.pop()  # keep one occurence
    [food.remove(meal) for o in occurences]  # remove the rest
  else:
    print('success: {}'.format(meal))

print(drinks)
print(food)
```

Comment: thank you, what if i want to add in another for loop for the food list?

Comment: @DanielWinser is the food loop part of the drinks loop or is the food loop it's own separate loop?

Comment: It is in a separate loop

Comment: @DanielWinser it's literally the same thing, just changing the variable names. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use set to check for uniqueness and intersects

```
drinks = []
food = []

drinks.append("lemontea")
drinks.append("coke")
drinks.append("sprite")
drinks.append("orangejuice")
drinks.append("fantagrape")

food.append("nugget")
food.append("pizza")
food.append("chickenwing")
food.append("fries")
food.append("pizza")

success = True
```

## unique

```
if len(set(food)) != len(food):
    print('fail: duplicate entry in food')
    success = False
if len(set(drinks)) != len(drinks):
    print('fail: duplicate entry in drinks')
    success = False
```

## in both lists

```
if set(food) & set(drinks):  # if the intersection of both sets is not empty
    print('fail: entry in both food and drinks')
    success = False
```

## success!

```
if success:
    print('success')
```